# Run a thread on a new core?

Tags: c, multithreading, process, operating-system, pthreads

Is there a way to tell the OS to run a process/thread on a separate core? To keep that process isolated?

Like using `pthreads` or `fork()` in C?

Is there a different way to do it in Linux vs Windows?

Comment: If you want to ensure that it runs on a separate core, then on Windows, you will probably need the functions [`SetProcessAffinityMask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setprocessaffinitymask) and [`SetThreadAffinityMask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadaffinitymask). However, that is not what `fork` does on UNIX. That function does not ensure that the new process runs on a separate core. It is up to the kernel's scheduler to decide whether it uses a different core or not.

Comment: Even if two processes use the same core, they will still be isolated, because their [virtual address spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) will be different. This isolation is ensured as part of a [CPU context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).